# Quarkus opentelemetry sampler

Tags: java, yaml, quarkus, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have the quarkus (v 2.13.x) opentelemetry working for our services. However, i am trying to provide a way to disable sending logs to the collector at the service level. I want to be able to drop sending the logs but still have the service participate in the trace/context propagation. The only runtime option i came across for this with Quarkus 2.13.x is the sampler. When i try the below sampler in the application.properties, it works.

```
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.sampler=ratio
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.sampler.ratio=0
```

However, when i try to define this in the application.yaml for runtime updates it doesn't work - it throws exception processing the yaml so doesn't even run. I have defined it as

```
quarkus:
  opentelemetry:
    tracer:
      sampler:
        ~: ratio
        ratio: 0
```

what's weird is i can change the configmap at run time to provide this setting and it works. I am not sure why i am not able to define this NULL parameter setting in the application.yaml.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus does not yet supports OpenTelemetry logging. Not sure why you are mixing logs and traces in this question.

In relation to traces, the config you are setting there is the equivalent to: `quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.sampler=off`
... And it will effectively disable all traces.

See: https://quarkus.io/version/2.13/guides/opentelemetry#sampler